# APC not clearing cache

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apc

I have a vps running Ubuntu 10.04 with nginx as the webserver and has 2GB RAM + 4GB SWAP. I'm using APC and noticed my cache isn't being deleted even though I have set apc.user_ttl to 7200. You can see the stats here http://negima.nu/apc.php

Does anyone know what the problem is and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using apc_clear_cache function ? There are two caches, one is system cache and secoond one is user cache

you can clear system cache as follows

```
apc_clear_cache()
```

user cache can be cleared as follows

```
apc_clear_cache('user')
```